# Excel Automation: Identifying and deleting blank work sheets

Tags: excel

I want to delete a worksheet if it contains no data/charts/images/drawing/hyperlink object or any other embedded objects.

I find out the solution of detecting and deleting blank sheets if there is no data in the cells by using the following code:-

if ( $Worksheet_Function->CountA( $sheet->{Cells} ) == 0 ) {
     $sheet->Delete;
}

but it also deletes the sheet if there are charts or non-text objects.

Is there any way to identify and delete sheets if its completely empty?

Answer (score 1):

will delete the sheet if there is only formatting, but this should do what you ask

```
Sub chksheet()
 Dim wks As Worksheet
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

 If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) = 0 And wks.DrawingObjects.Count = 0 Then
  wks.Delete
  Else
   MsgBox ("has stuff") 'or do nothing here and skip this sheet
  End If
 Next wks

 Set wks = Nothing
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can be more thorough and go through all the related objects you want to test

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With WS
        'default usedrange = 1 so check cell A1 is also empty
        If .UsedRange.Count = 1 And IsEmpty(.Cells(1, 1).Value) _
            And .UsedRange.Column = 1 _
            And .UsedRange.Row = 1 _
            And .Comments.Count = 0 _
            And .Shapes.Count = 0 _
            And .Hyperlinks.Count = 0 _
            And .ListObjects.Count = 0 _
            And .OLEObjects.Count = 0 _
            And .Names.Count = 0 _
            And .QueryTables.Count = 0 _
            And .SmartTags.Count = 0 Then

            MsgBox ("BLANK")
            'WS.delete
        Else
            MsgBox ("NOT BLANK")
        End If

        End With
Next WS
End Sub
```